# iMac g4 OS X installation issue

Tags: macos

I was formatting my iMac g4 for installing OS 10.4. When half of the installation was completed, power failure occur which caused interrupt in installation.

Now when i had restarted my iMac PPC it shows flashing folder icon. I had tried googling but didn't find any working solution. I am unable to find hard drive when installing os as when system boots up no hard drive is shown and when i try to boot from DVD it constantly ejects up the DVD and refuse to boot from DVD and sometimes system hangs on boot also. I had tried restarting like around 15 times but nothing is works out. Does my Hard Drive gone as after seeing some videos and post it seems to me that my hard disk is probably dead.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That flashing icon appears because of 2 cause/reasons

```
If there is some loose connection between physical drive and motherboard
If file system of OS is damaged
```

And according to your question i think your problem is of second type. I think you can probably try to zappram(reset RAM) when your system boots press Command+Option+P+R keys, you will then hear the Mac reboot sound(chime) again.

Now press option key wait for some time till system reads DVD contents. Now click on reload or refresh icon if you are lucky than you'll be able to see boot from DVD option